# How to display videos in grid layout and play on press React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, grid-layout

I am displaying a set of images in a grid layout. But when i add video url to the same nothing is displayed in the grid layout. All i see is a blank space. How can I add videos to a grid layout and on press play it in a modal?

My Code for GridLayout:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Modal, Dimensions, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

import ImageElement from './ImageElement';

export default class GridLayoutSample extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
  this.state={
    modalVisible: false,
    modalImage: require('./download (1).jpeg'),
    images:[
      require('./download.png'),
      require('./android/app/img/51049911-nice-france-august-15-2015-subway-fast-food-restaurant-interior-subway-is-an-american-fast-food-rest.jpg'),
      require('./android/app/img/dominos.jpg'),
      require('./android/app/img/0.jpeg'),
      //{ uri: "https://luehangs.site/pic-chat-app-images/animals-avian-beach-760984.jpg" },
                //{ url: "https://luehangs.site/pic-chat-app-images/beautiful-beautiful-woman-beauty-9763.jpg" },
                //{ URL: "https://luehangs.site/pic-chat-app-images/attractive-balance-beautiful-186263.jpg" },
    ]
  }
}

setModalVisible(visible, imagekey){
  this.setState({modalImage: this.state.images[imagekey]});
  this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
}

getImage(){
  return this.state.modalImage;
}
  render(){
    let images = this.state.images.map((val,key) => {
      return<TouchableWithoutFeedback key={key}
      onPress={()=> {this.setModalVisible(true, key)}}>
      <View style={styles.imagewrap}>
      <ImageElement imgsource={val}></ImageElement>
      </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    });
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>


      <Modal style={styles.modal} animationType={'fade'}
      transparent={true} visible={this.state.modalVisible} onRequestClose={()=>{}}>

      <View style={styles.modal}>
      <Text style={styles.text} onPress={()=>{
        this.setModalVisible(false)}}>Close</Text>
        <ImageElement imgsource={this.state.modalImage}></ImageElement>   
      </View>

      </Modal>
      {images}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  backgroundColor: '#eee',
},
imagewrap:{
  margin: 2,
  padding: 2,
  height: (Dimensions.get('window').height/3)-12,
  width: (Dimensions.get('window').width/2)-4,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
modal:{
  flex:1,
  padding: 40,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.9)',
},
text:{
  color: '#fff',
},
})
```

> **ImageElement.js : This is the code for ImageElement.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';

export default class GridLayoutSample extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Image source={this.props.imgsource} style={styles.image}>
      </Image>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image:{
    flex:1,
    width: null,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) for rendering video's in your application. If yes then I have gone through same problem once. What I did was we don't have thumbnail support from **react-native video**. I did it as follows

```
<Video
      source={{ uri: source of your video }}
      style={[{ width: null, height: null, flex:1 }]}
      paused
 />
```

This will pause the video and will show as image (first frame of video), embed it with TouchableOpacity. On click on that show in modal with fullscreen.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi Maneesh. Can you share this with a sample code which will help me understand better. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Abhirup, I have already provided the code which you need to replace with **Image Tag**  in your **ImageElement.js** file as `<TouchableOpcity><Video
      source={{ uri: source of your video }}
      style={[{ width: null, height: null, flex:1 }]}
      paused
 /></TouchableOpacity>`

Answer (score 0):

Video url passed to a `Image` tag would not show any image.

You could pass a thumbnail representing the video. onPress of the image, open modal and play video. Would suggest you to use this library to play the video [react-native-af-video-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-af-video-player). It comes with added video player components and is built over `react-native-video`. On load of the video the package auto loades a thumbnail or if you want there is a prop to add your own thumbnail.

Hope this helps. Please do comment if you want any sample code.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Would be helpful if you could post a sample code. PS: i'm trying to display both images and videos in the gridlayout.

Comment: Could you share a sample design of what you want to achieve. That will help me assist you with a sample code.

Comment: In a grid layout I want to display images and video files. On press of image a modal opens up and the image is displayed. Similarly, for the video on press of the video it should play.

Comment: But how will you identify whether it is Image or Video. I have also gone through same issue, but I got response from backend whether it is video or Image. Are you able to get same??

Comment: @AbhirupMukherjee join this room. [Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189528/gridlayout-sample)

Comment: Yeah @Maneesh i'm declaring a prop type for both images and video and also getting the response from backend. The prop type can be used to determine the kind whether it is image or video.

Comment: Then by using `Ternary operator` try to bind both images and videos as per prop type.